# Integrate ESRI data with Mapstraction

Tags: esri, mapstraction

Is it possible to integrate data from ESRI with Mapstraction. Do anyone got any idea in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment ArcGIS providers aren't supported by mapstraction. If you don't want to use the official javascript, flex or silverlight api from ESRI then you can use OpenLayers.